# ko foreach not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout-2.0

I have reviewed all related artilcle that I have found, and others seem to be able to get this simple code to work

I am using jquery-1.9.1, jquery-mobile-1.3.0, and knockout-2.2.1.  I am providing this because I have come to realize that many times these libraries can be incompatible.  I have not been able to find a good resource that spells out which of these libraries should be used together.

My problem is I can bind an obserable array using a template, but can't get the knockout containerless foreach to work.

This works:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-insert="true" data-bind="template: { name: 'OfficeTemplate', foreach: CampaignTeams, as: 'Team' }"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="OfficeTemplate">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: TeamName"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

This does not work:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: CampaignTeams-->
    <li>
        <h1>
            <span data-bind="text: TeamName"></span>
        </h1>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

This going to get much more complicated and I intend to use nested templates, the clean in-line binding is much preferred.

What I have noticed debugging this is that the ko.applyBindings(vm) fails when using the containerless syntax.

View Model:

```
var vm = {
    // data
    CampaignTeams: ko.observableArray(null)
};

    // Get Office Summary
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
            , url: "/api/SalesTeamData/GetOfficeSummary/?Campaign=" + Campaign
            , datatype: "json"
            , data: ""
            , success: function (data) {
                vm.CampaignTeams = ko.observableArray(data);
                ko.applyBindings(vm);
                $('li[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({ theme: 'c', refresh: true });
            }
            , error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
    });
```

Comment: We can't know what's failing without more code. Can you put up something on jsfiddle.net that shows the problem?

Comment: I've had foreaches fail a lot for me as well.  It's very frustrating and I haven't been able to figure why it fails sometimes and not others.

Comment: @carl where is the actual forEach? Aren't you supposed to have data-bind="foreach CAmpaignTeams" in the UL like in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum he's using the alternative syntax for some reason, which I'm not entirely sure can be used with a foreach.

Comment: Try it without using data-role and data-insert.  Isolate the problem.  It may be the data-bind attribute, it may be your viewmodel.  Without more code we cannot tell.

Comment: I think the view model is fine because the top example works, I also tried the syntax where the foreach is embedded in the <ul> tag, when it did not work, I read and article on stack overflow that suggested the commented version was more consistent to I tried that, neither is working

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I just deleted my comment :/ I realized the link I posted myself had an example using this syntax. I used Knockout on a project before and didn't even realize this sort of syntax was an option. Learn something new every day

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Didn't even notice myself =P

Comment: the view model is pretty simple, just an observalbe array populated with a ajax call:

Comment: I had the data-role and data-insert in there, did not seem to make a difference in the foreach, I removed them from the example to simplify

Comment: what is the error you get when you say the applyBindings fail for containerless binding?

Comment: I did not debug the ko script, it just did not execute any script after the ko.applybindings call

Answer (score 0):

```
 var vm = {
    // data
    CampaignTeams: ko.observableArray([])
 };

ko.applyBindings(vm);
// Get Office Summary
$.ajax({
    type: "GET"
        , url: "/api/SalesTeamData/GetOfficeSummary/?Campaign=" + Campaign
        , datatype: "json"
        , data: ""
        , success: function (data) {
            vm.CampaignTeams(data);
            $('li[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({ theme: 'c', refresh: true });
        }
        , error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
});
```

Comment: this should work and the virtual element syntax too should work